# How to sum all data in an excel file that contains specific data

Tags: excel

Hope someone can help me out on this.

I have an excel file which has different data. Here's a screenshot of the actual data: http://prntscr.com/fg0q2m

What I want to happen is this:

I want to get the sum of all specific "Service Presence Status:API Name" which has the same value per user.

Example: I want to get the total duration Christian Aguda used the status "Available for Email" for each specific day.

Hope you can shed some light, folks.

Thanks!

Comment: Use SUMIFS function

Comment: Can you send me a sample formula?

Comment: SUMIFS: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Answer (score 0):

Use
SUMIFS formula to get sum of your defined criteria
COUNTIFS formula to get count of your defined criteria

Below mentioned link of sumifs formula example
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function